# JS does nothing... trying to change a class in a <ul> <li>

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I can't get anything to change the "class" attribute with JS... I've searched for several hours, can't see anything else to try.... here's the source: (note I'm doing this on my laptop, locally...

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>jS chg class</title>
    </head>
    <script>
    var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (int i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++)
     {
      if (listitems[i].className == "trash")
      {
       listitems[i].className = "keep";
       break;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <body>


        <div id="junk">


            <span id="categorylabel">Closet Junk:</span>
            <ul id="junklist">
                <li class="trash">books</li>
                <li class="trash">shoes</li>
                <li class="trash">clothes</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: put the script block after the body

Comment: 1. This is JavaScript, not C. 2. Put scripts at the end of the body.

Comment: When writing JS have the JS console of your browser's dev tools open: errors will be reported there (such as `int` is not a keyword in JS).

Answer (score 2):

use `var` instead of `int` in the for loop like this:

```
var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
  if (listitems[i].className == "trash") {console.log("sdfg")
     listitems[i].className = "keep";
     break;
  }
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/4wxer477/)

Answer (score 2):

as gurvinder372 comment... put `<script>` tags to end of `<body>`'s bottom.

and. Thinker's answer (change `int` to `var` in your `for` loop)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jS chg class</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    .trash { color : red; }
  </style>
<body>

<div id="junk">
  <span id="categorylabel">Closet Junk:</span>
  <ul id="junklist">
      <li class="trash">books</li>
      <li class="trash">shoes</li>
      <li class="trash">clothes</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script> ///// HERE
  var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) // and HERE
  {
    if (listitems[i].className == "trash")
    {
      listitems[i].className = "keep";
      break;
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied the entire thing, made no changes, loaded into editor (Notepad++), saved it, loaded the page, no joy... Shouldn't I be able to see this when I "view source"?  again, I'm running this on my laptop, a webserver... this shouldn't matter, should it?

Comment: well... I added style. see difference.

Comment: I see the first <li> black, the next 2 red... should I be able to see this change in "view source" from the browser?

Comment: no, you just can not. view source's just shows raw (initial) source what browser received from server. when you modify DOM, it does not change original source. but you can explore with browser's debug tool. use chrome and inspect dom. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must apply Javascript after document is ready.

Try this:

```
(function() {
    ...
    your script
    ...
})();
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/kLk7g7L1/)

Comment: pardon me. but the matter is when not how. check out - https://jsfiddle.net/0hua0je0/

Comment: I think you mean, jQuery's `$(function() { ... })` that bind to document.ready event. :) it can be anywhere in document. (or script)

Comment: Yes i think, you can bind JQuery or use your script the end of the body! @YourimYi

Answer (score 0):

Here are the following issues.

1. You have put the js inside head tag. When this will be parsed there wont be any DOM element `li`. If you want to keep it inside `head` put it inside `window.onload`
2. Like java there is no variable type declaration in javascript. All variables of any type be it string or number or anything else is declared using [**var**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword
3. When you are using the break keyword, your logic will only match the first element and will come out of the loop. So you may need to remove the break keyword

Check this snippet

```
var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++){
      if (listitems[i].className == "trash")
      {
       listitems[i].className = "keep";
       //break;
      }
    }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/7pt7668L/)

Note: Un-comment break in the jsfiddle to replicate the issue

Comment: I copied your code as is, put it where you advised... I reloaded the page... no joy... shouldn't I be able to see the change when I view source? again, I am running this locally, on my laptop...

Comment: see developers tool for error? are you putting the code inside head tag?

Comment: I tried both <head> and <body> , no joy... I just want ONE example of this so I can change some similar code elsewhere, but I can't get this example to do anything... I've tried no less than 15 different solutions... Not ONE produced any results... again, should I be seeing the rendered result when I "view source"?  it seems like  there's something not working... running LOCAL, opening page in Firefox...